# markojs data variable access in client side javascript

Tags: marko

i am setting array of json objects into data variable like this data.journeyDetail = detail; in marko file i need to access it inside javascript block and for each record need to print FullName from the object. how to do this?

server side code:

```
 data.journeyDetail = detail;
 data.author = "najam";
 this.body = marko.load("./views/journeyDetail.marko").stream(data);
```

marko file(client side)

```
    <script>
    console.log("author=$data.journeyDetail.length");
    var length = $data.journeyDetail.length;
    var recs = $data.journeyDetail;
    console.log("len=", length);
    console.log("array=", array);
    for(var i=0; length; i++){
      console.log("counter=", recs[i].origin);
    }

   </script>
```

when page is rendering its giving javascript error and line that has error have invalid assignment 
var recs = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object];
    console.log("len=", length);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to *serialize* the template data to the page using `JSON.stringify(...)`. This will allow the code within your `script` to access the data that was first available when the template was rendered. Keep in mind, that your `data.journeyDetail` data cannot have circular references because this will cause error to be thrown in `JSON.stringify(...)`. You might want to use `Array` `map` function to transform the data in the array if you don't need all of the information when your script code runs.

You'll want to use:

```
<script>
console.log("author=$data.journeyDetail.length");
var length = $data.journeyDetail.length;
var recs = ${JSON.stringify(data.journeyDetail)};
console.log("len=", length);
console.log("array=", array);
for(var i=0; length; i++){
  console.log("counter=", recs[i].origin);
}
</script>
```

The only change was this line:

```
var recs = ${JSON.stringify(data.journeyDetail)};
```

Comment: Slight correction: `var recs = ${JSON.stringify(data.journeyDetail)};` (without the double quotes)